# How can I figure out the dependency paths for Android support libraries?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I am trying to build an Android app with minimum SDK version of 23. I believe I need to import support libraries v4, v7 and Design for my project. I have tried guessing, but my gradle sync keeps giving "Failed to resolve" errors. Reading the Android Developer documentation doesn't help me to figure out the correct path values for the dependencies. How can I do that?

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: post the complete error trace

Comment: The libraries you mention are compatibility libraries. With minSdkVersion=23 you should not need them. You can use the original classes instead. Only if you want to use an API24 feature you have to use them, but then the `:24.?.?` versions.

Comment: I am trying to use TabLayout. It is included in the Design support library. More than that, I want to know how to define correct dependency paths in case I need to import a library.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `file -> Project Structure --> Modules --> app --> Dependencies --> + --> Library Dependency --> "searchterm" --> Ok`

You will have the right libraries

Comment: That filters out results from my installed libraries and adds correct import paths in my gradle file? If so, it should answer my question.

Comment: That tool seems to give only latest versions. What if I want to choose from earlier versions?

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to do it.

- Right click on the main project folder.
- Select `Module Settings`. You can use the <kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut instead to access this.
- Go to the `Dependencies` tab.
- Add a dependency and select `Library Dependency`.
- Search for the dependancies you with to add and click ok once you're
  done.

This will update the gradle file automatically.

Hope this helps :)